# Why I can't iterate through 2 points in time?

Tags: python, datetime, iteration

My task is to get a list of all possible variations of time between 02:19:30 and 11:09:29, so it be: [02:19:30, 02:19:31, ... , 11:09:29].

I wrote this piece of code to iterate through seconds('print' will be replaced by list appending):

```
start_time = datetime.time(2, 19, 30)
end_time = datetime.time(11, 9, 29)
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

while start_time != end_time:
    print(str(start_time))
    start_time += delta
```

But I keep getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\PythonProjects\Python-lab5\main.py", line 16, in 
start_time += delta
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

What is wrong?

Comment: You MRE is longer than it needs to be. You can remove everything besides the illegal operation `start_time + delta`.

Comment: Don't use `!=`, use `<` and use it with `datetime.datetime`.  Too much possibility of an infinite loop otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time`s are "abstract" as it is - you'll need to work with full `datetime`s if you want to do arithmetic with them.

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 2, 19, 30)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 11, 9, 29)
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

while start_time != end_time:
    print(str(start_time.time()))
    start_time += delta
```